# ISP, broken routes and my options

Tags: networking, routing, isp, static-routes

My ISP has serious routing problem. First, I've confirmed that my Internet connection is indeed working:

```
rr-@burza:~(1:3) $ ping -c 4 -W 1 status.github.com
PING octostatus-production.github.com (184.73.4.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from status.github.com (184.73.4.42): icmp_req=1 ttl=45 time=129 ms
64 bytes from status.github.com (184.73.4.42): icmp_req=2 ttl=45 time=129 ms
64 bytes from status.github.com (184.73.4.42): icmp_req=3 ttl=45 time=129 ms
64 bytes from status.github.com (184.73.4.42): icmp_req=4 ttl=45 time=129 ms

--- octostatus-production.github.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 129.013/129.241/129.692/0.371 ms
```

Then, to show that the problem lies on my ISP's end:

```
rr-@burza:~(1:5) $ ping -c 4 -W 1 github.com
PING github.com (204.232.175.90) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- github.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3022ms
```

As you can see, the problem isn't related  to DNS since `github.com` resolves nicely to `204.232.175.90`. Finally, output of trace route:

```
rr-@burza:~(1:11) $ traceroute-nanog -m 15 github.com
traceroute to github.com (204.232.175.90), 15 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  Broadcom.Bifrost (192.168.1.1)  0.278 ms  0.252 ms  0.417 ms
 2  poz-bg3.neo.tpnet.pl (83.1.4.175)  27.310 ms  27.558 ms  27.114 ms
 3  poz-r3.tpnet.pl (80.50.118.1)  27.287 ms  30.047 ms  27.937 ms
 4  poz-r2.tpnet.pl (194.204.175.206)  26.081 ms  42.772 ms  26.381 ms
 5  hbg-b1-link.telia.net (213.248.103.61)  37.468 ms  37.666 ms  49.427 ms
 6  hbg-bb1-link.telia.net (80.91.253.55)  37.905 ms  37.692 ms  37.634 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  rackspace-ic-138625-ash-bb1.c.telia.net (213.248.98.218)  130.394 ms  129.907 ms  130.421 ms
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
```

In before, github.com accepts ICMP ping requests, because on computer belonging to another network I can do following:

```
s351821@shell:~(1:1) $ ping -c 4 -W 1 github.com
PING github.com (204.232.175.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from github.com (204.232.175.90): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=111 ms
64 bytes from github.com (204.232.175.90): icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=111 ms
64 bytes from github.com (204.232.175.90): icmp_req=3 ttl=51 time=111 ms
64 bytes from github.com (204.232.175.90): icmp_req=4 ttl=51 time=111 ms

--- github.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 111.450/111.621/111.941/0.195 ms
```

Furthermore problem isn't limited to github.com - a lot of other Internet sites do not work.

My ISP has confirmed the problem and told me that they will fix it by the end of the week.

My question is: **what can I do myself?**

Can I manually set up some static routes that will allow me to access github.com (and other sites) - and if so, how can I do it? Additionally, *when* my ISP actually fixes the problem, am I required to reboot my own router in order to let things propagate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I manually set up some static routes that will allow me to access
>   github.com (and other sites)

No. Your traffic is routing properly out of your host, via 0.0.0.0/0.

> Additionally, when my ISP actually fixes the problem, am I required to
>   reboot my own router in order to let things propagate?

No. Your routes are set up correctly, there's nothing to propagate.

The only way to fix this is to tunnel your traffic out through to a properly functioning host and have it proxy traffic. See [https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+tunnel](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh%20tunnel).